# How can I have `less` automatically decompress `xz` files like it did with `gz` files on my old SUSE distro?

Tags: linux, less, opensuse-12.2, xz

On my old SUSE distro, `less` would automatically decompress .[gz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) files.

That came in very convenient when listing auto-compressed `/var/log/mail*.gz` files.

The current version of SUSE now archives `/var/log/mail` and others with [xz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz).

I never wondered how `less` automatically decompressed .[gz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) files, but I probably should have (:

So: what do I need to do, so this "magically" will work:

```
less /var/log/mail-20130201.xz
```

I regard this as a Linux question, but in case it is SUSE specific, I'm running this version of SUSE:

```
openSUSE 12.2 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12.2
CODENAME = Mantis
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality is provided by [lesspipe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lesspipe/). Install it and put (I don't have a SUSE machine at the moment to check)

```
[ -x /usr/bin/lessopen.sh ] && eval /usr/bin/lessopen.sh
```

in your shell configuration (e.g., `.bashrc`)

Comment: Thanks. Getting it to install and work was a bit of work, see my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Matteo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lesspipe/) for [pointing me into the right direction](https://superuser.com/questions/559729/how-can-i-have-less-automatically-decompress-xz-files-like-it-did-with-gz/559731#559731).

Getting [lesspipe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lesspipe/) to run on OpenSUSE was a bit of a journey as it is not part of the standard OpenSUSE 12.x repository. You can only get 'unstable' lesspipe packages, of which the Show home:adra / lesspipe - openSUSE Build Service seems to be maintained most frequently.

This is how to install it from there:

```
zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:adra/openSUSE_Factory/home:adra.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install lesspipe
```

I am using the bash shell, so after performing the install, I had to add this line to my my ~/.bashrc

```
LESSOPEN="|lesspipe.sh %s"; export LESSOPEN
```